# Cursor error when using aggregation for MongoDB in Java driver

Tags: mongodb, cursor, aggregate, mongo-java-driver

I want to aggregate by group, then sort and limit. Here's my code:

```
        if(m!=null){
            db = m.getDB("FMdb");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("user_artists");
            DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$artistID").append("total", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$weight")));
            DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("total", -1));
            DBObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1);

            List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(group,sort,limit);
            AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
            for (DBObject d : output.results()){System.out.println(d);}
        }
```

Here is the error message from bash:

`Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find many similar errors here and couldn't find a solution before. It turns out the code itself is fine. The problems is incompatibility of MongoDB and java-drive package.
My MongoDB version is v4.0.9. 
My previous java-drive package was 3.0.0-beta1.
After updated the package to 3.8.0, my codes posted worked perfectly ever since.

If you confront similar errors, you can find the package here.
[mongo-java-driver-3.8.0.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.8.0/mongo-java-driver-3.8.0.jar)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was not able to compile your code, not sure what the namespaces are, and you did not include them.  Here is an example where every object is fully qualified.  I think this is working as you want.  I believe the objective is to find the artist having the most entries and provide the count of entries for that artist...

```
private static void Aggregate2(com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db) {
    com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = db.getCollection("user_artists");
    com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable<org.bson.Document> aggregateIterable = collection.aggregate(java.util.Arrays.asList(
        com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.group("$artistID", com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.sum("total", 1)), 
        new org.bson.Document("$sort", new org.bson.Document("total", -1)),
        new org.bson.Document("$limit", 1)
     ));

    for(org.bson.Document document : aggregateIterable) {
        String json = document.toJson();
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```